# Django CMS CSS styling

Tags: django, django-templates, content-management-system, django-cms

so I’m working with Django and I’m trying to figure out how in the edit the CSS using nothing but Django CMS?

Is there a way?
Anything would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Django CMS does not have any inline editing features of CSS or any other markup. This is by design and it is not something like Wordpress.

To edit CSS you will need to create your own css files as part of your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add eg an HTML or CSS snippet into a page, there's an offical plugin for that  - https://github.com/django-cms/djangocms-snippet

And as @Aiky30 said, the global CSS code is better to place in `static` in accordance with django best practices.